# Ivy buildnumber not working

Tags: java, configuration, build, ivy

I am trying to get [`ivy:buildnumber`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/buildnumber.html) working for my build's `publish` target and am getting a bizarre error.

My `publish` target:

```
<target name="publish" depends="package">
    <ivy:buildnumber resolver="default-resolver" organisation="myorg" module="myapp" revision="0.2" />
    <ivy:publish resolver="default-resolver" pubrevision="${ivy.new.revision}" overwrite="true" update="true">   
        <artifacts pattern="gen/dist/pub/[artifact].[ext]" />   
    </ivy:publish>
</target>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
publish:
[ivy:buildnumber] :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/myuser/sandbox/dsi/workbench/eclipse/4.2/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ivy.eclipse.ant_2.3.0.final_20130110142753/ivy.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/myuser/sandbox/dsi/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/build/build-core.xml:289: Unknown resolver: default-resolver
```

**The thing is, my Ivy settings file is not located at `org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml`.** My Ivy settings file is located at `~/ivy/ivy-settings.xml`.

So I *think* somehow I'm not configuring `ivy:buildnumber` correctly, and so it's defaulting to whatever Ivy settings file that Ivy ships with. And since my `default-resolver` isn't defined in that shipped settings file, it can't find a resolver to publish against.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

My `<ivy:settings>` target:

```
<target name="setup-ivy">
    <ivy:settings url="file:///home/myuser/ivy/ivy-settings.xml"/>
</target>
```

And my `ivy-settings.xml`:

```
<ivysettings>  
    <properties file="ivy-settings.properties"/>
    <settings defaultResolver="default-resolver"/>
    <latest-strategies>
        <latest-lexico/>
    </latest-strategies>
    <credentials host="${ivy.repo.root}" realm="${ivy.std.repo.realm}" username="${ivy.std.repo.username}" password="${ivy.std.repo.password}"/>
    <resolvers>  
        <chain name="default-resolver" returnFirst="true">
            <url name="std-repo">
                <ivy pattern="${ivy.repo.root}/${ivy.module.pattern}"/>
                <artifact pattern="${ivy.repo.root}/${ivy.artifact.pattern}"/>
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>  
    <modules>
        <module organisation="myorg" name="*" resolver="default-resolver"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Are you sure your "publish" target is actually calling the "setup-ivy" target. Follow your "package" target and see if this is really the case.

Comment: Thanks @EyadEbrahim (+1) - yes `publish` calls `package`, which calls `compile` which calls `resolve` (which is where `ivy:resolve` and `ivy:retrieve` happen), which in turns calls `setup-ivy`

Answer (score 0):

The default location for a custom *ivysettings.xml* file is alongside the *ivy.xml* file.

Another alternative is to use one of the following tasks to explicitly state which ivy settings file to use:

- [configure](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/configure.html)
- [settings](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/settings.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mark O'Connor (+1) - but I already have Ivy working great pulling down Ivy libs from a local Artifactory instance.  I have Ivy settings configured properly and pointed at `~/ivy/ivy-settings.xml`. I will update my answer with my Ivy settings task and Ivy settings file in a few mins. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my original post with my Ivy settings task and `ivy-settings.xml` file. With the current set up, I am able to specify `myapp`'s dependencies in an `ivy.xml` file and pull them down from my local Artifactory server. I now need to publish `myapp-0.2.0.jar` to that same Artifactory server, and would like to use `ivy:buildnumber` to manage version numbers for me.